# SCARA robot configuration subtype (first axis vertical)

Tags: robotic-arm, design

I'm working on a project where I need a SCARA where the first axis is the linear / vertical one (as often seen in hobbyist configurations). Something like this: 
https://www.igus.eu/product/21104?C=DE&L=en&artNr=RL-SCR-0101

I'm trying to find similar robots (or even a horizontal arm by itself - e. g. this https://www.igus.eu/product/21105?C=DE&L=en&artNr=RL-SCR-0102) with similar specs to compare. It won't be lifting heavy loads (max. 500 g) and won't need to go fast at all. It will need a pretty large vertical range though (up to 2 m depending on the final specs of the project). That's why I was thinking about going with an arm like the mentioned one bolted to a linear rail.

Does anyone have some recommendations or maybe just some keywords with which I could find something similar.
If you need any additional information let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Staubli used to make a robot arm called the TS20 or earlier RS20 which was a small 20 cm reach scara with the vertical axis over the base instead of on the end of the arm. It was small for a commercial arm and had a light payload, nominal 0.5 KG maximum 1 KG. It was intended for the education market, schools and universities. The sales numbers were low and Staubli stop making them a couple of years ago.

You see an image at https://www.automate.org/products/staubli-robotics/ts20-scara-robot

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple listed on the [Qviro](https://qviro.com/product-category/scara-robots) website. Qviro is a sort of robots review/compare website.